# jQuery events: notify the newly created elements of past events

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Code example:

```
var Events = $({});

Events.on('myCustomEvent', function(){ console.log('myCustomEvent 1') })

Events.trigger('myCustomEvent'); // I want notify the previous binds and all binds in future

$.ajax({...}).success(function(res){
    Events.on('myCustomEvent', function(){ console.log('myCustomEvent 2') })
});

// when ajax or other long process will be finished 'myCustomEvent' must be fired
```

'myCustomEvent 1' will be printed because its binded before trigger will called and
'myCustomEvent 2' must be trigged too

Is it any solutions in jQuery?

Comment: @thecodeparadox an empty javascript object inside a jQuery object.

Comment: How can `myCustomEvent 2` be shown if the handler has not been assigned at the moment you trigger the event? If `myCustomEvent` is a one-time thing you might want to use deferred objects instead. If you add new callbacks to a resolved deferred object, they will be called immediately. But to decide whether this is a viable solution, you'd have to provide more information about your actual problem. What are you trying to achieve? What do you need this  for?

Comment: It can show only the events that is bound at that point when the trigger is executed.

Comment: @Felix Kling unfortunately I use many libraries where I cant integrate deferred objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you want is not so much events as it is a pub/sub system, or code which implements the Observer pattern. Most of these implementations do not have the ability to retroactively call subscribers, after a message has been published. I've done it, but you need to be careful that anyone using the system knows a message may be published many times. Unfortunately, I can't share the code, since it's owned by my employer.

Just doing a search for "observer pattern in JavaScript" or "pubsub in JavaScript" will get you a good library. Typically these use a hash of a "topic" to an array of functions which are called when that topic is published. The trick is to also keep a history of when publish is called. When someone subscribes to a topic which is already published, re-publish that topic.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: I want to combine Events with something like Deferred objects

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is a $.Callbacks

```
Callbacks.highlight = $.Callbacks('memory')

// ComponentB
$(window).hashchange(function(){

    $.ajax({ /* load items of #ListB */ }).success(function(data){

        /* append items to dom */

        if (/listA=123/.test(location.hash))
            Callbacks.highlight.fire();
    })

    $('#ListB').on('click', 'a', function(){ /* highlight the same in #ListA by alg2 */ })
})

// ComponentA
$(window).hashchange(function(){

    $.ajax({ /* load items of #ListA */ }).success(function(data){

        /* append items to dom */
        Callbacks.highlight.add( /* highlight item */ )
    })

    $('#ListA').on('click', 'a', function(){ /* highlight the same in #ListB by alg1 */ })
})
```